# display bash result in os x notification center today widget

Tags: macos, swift, today-extension

Suppose I want to display the mouse battery level in a today widget in os x notification center. The bash command

```
ioreg -c BNBMouseDevice | grep BatteryPercent | sed 's/[a-z,A-Z, ,|,",=]//g' | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}'
```

gives the string to be displayed. How to pass this value to a text field in `todayviewcontroller.xib`? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a code snippet that creates a string out of a sample bash command output:

```
let task = NSTask()
task.launchPath = "/bin/bash"
task.arguments = ["-c", "echo Hi!"]

let outputPipe = NSPipe()
task.standardOutput = outputPipe

task.launch()
task.waitUntilExit()

let data = outputPipe.fileHandleForReading.availableData
if data.length > 0 {
    let output = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
}
```

Substitute with your command, set the `output` to your text field `stringValue` and you're done.